# What does "pull" mean in "Didn't he pull this...?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the cars 3 movie , there's a quote of one character that is

> McQueen's still not here? Didn't he **pull** this when he was a rookie? At least that's what my grandfather told me.

Context: In the first movie of the franchise, when McQueen was a rookie he didn't show up in time for the race, and the same thing happens in the Cars 3 movie, so when one of the racers is asked about McQueen he answered that.

Could someone explain what "pull" means in that sentence?
I never saw pull being used with that meaning.

Comment: Did you look up "[pull](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull)" in a dictionary? There are a lot of meanings, but did you think about which ones could work there?

Comment: I think none of them works in the sentence , I tried all of them

Comment: The relevant meaning of pull is to do something silly, stupid or irresponsible, such as a prank.

Comment: Could you please send me a dictionary with such definition ? I really didn't find it

Comment: It would help if you told us which definitions you did find and why those didn't help.

Comment: exert force on (someone or something) so as to cause movement toward oneself.
"he pulled them down onto the couch"
Similar:
tug
haul
drag
draw
trail
tow
heave
lug
strain at
jerk
lever
prise
wrench
wrest
twist
pry
yank
Opposite:
push
2.
(of a vehicle or person) move steadily in a specified direction or to reach a specified point.

Comment: There are de meaning I found , and none of them work in the sentence

Comment: Please guys help me :(

Answer (score 1):

The verb "pull" in this context is approximately what was mentioned in a comment:
`to do something silly, stupid or irresponsible, such as a prank.`

There are a number of idioms that use "pull" this way:
pull a fast one
pull a prank
pull something
pull a stunt
pull a trick

**The central meaning of "pull" in these idioms is to do something that is not legitimate, in the eye of the speaker.**

Here are some dictionary references that support that, though they may not fit the exact structure in your example:

[American Heritage Dictionary "pull"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pull)
idioms:
pull something
To carry out a deception or swindle: *worried that his partners might be trying to pull something behind his back.*
pull a fast one Informal
To play a trick or perpetrate a fraud.

[Merriam-Webster "pull"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull)
8b : commit, perpetrate *pull a robbery, pull a prank*

[Collins Dictionary "pull"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pull)
15. verb
To pull a stunt or a trick on someone means to do something dramatic or silly in order to get their attention or trick them.
[informal]
*Everyone saw the stunt you pulled on me.*

[Collins Dictionary "pull a fast one"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-pull-a-fast-one)
If you say that someone has pulled a fast one on you, you mean that they have cheated or tricked you.